# Create folder based on lines in file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a lot of folders at once. I have a text file that contains all the names I need. But I'm not able to use this file as an "input".

Here's my code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (listfolder.txt) do (
    set name=%%A
    xcopy /i /e "C:\Users\Documents\00 template" "C:\Users\Documents\%name%"
)
```

I also tried

```
xcopy /i /e "C:\Users\Documents\00 template" "C:\Users\Documents\" AND %name%
```

and

```
xcopy /i /e "C:\Users\Documents\00 template" "C:\Users\Documents\" AND %%A
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Pretty new to batch - For example, `"tokens=*"` I don't get the reason behind this. I just find the information on internet.

Thanks all,

Comment: typical [delayed expansion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), but you don't need the `name` variable. Just ` xcopy /i /e "C:\Users\Documents\00 template" "C:\Users\Documents\%%A"`

Comment: `for /?` should answer your question about `tokens` and `delims`.

Comment: Stephan : Thanks. It seems that it was the only option I did not test!
I can confirm that it works actually. Mind to write an answer and I mark it as answer ? :)

Comment: There are literally hundreds of such questions. No need to add another identical answer. I marked your question as a duplicate of one of them.